# How can I index into a vhdl std_logic_vector?

Tags: vhdl

I have the following declarations:

```
signal count:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
signal txbuff:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
```

1. dout is a `std_logic` output
2. I am using `IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL`;

I want to use the vector count as an index into txbuff.  Among the many things I've tried is the following:

```
count<=std_logic_vector(unsigned(count)-1);
dout<=txbuff(unsigned(count));
```

but I get the following error:

> Line 99. Wrong index type for txbuff.

Comment: Notice that count has a length of 4 and can index 2**4 elements, which txbuff only has a length of 8 (8 elements).  Using a larger integer index can result in a slice name `dout<=txbuff(to_integer(unsigned(count)));` that's out of range for txbuff causing a run time error.  Bill Lynch implies this in his answer. In your case that would be `dout<=txbuff(to_integer(unsigned(count(2 downto 0))));`, or can you change the size of count?

Answer (score 5):

You need an integer as the index type. (Or with other arrays, you can use any discrete type, such as as enumeration).

Other answers have showed you how to get there using type conversion functions : I'll ask instead, why not make "count" an integer, like `natural range 0 to 15` in the first place? It'll synthesise just the same, and make for cleaner simpler code.

Answer (score 3):

We actually want to convert the number to an `integer`, not an `unsigned` or `signed`.

To do this, we can use `to_integer` as defined in `numeric_std`. Here's an example:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity conv_test is Port (
    data_in  : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    data_sel : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    data_out : out std_logic
);
end conv_test;

architecture Behavioral of conv_test is
begin
    data_out <= data_out(to_integer(unsigned(data_sel)));
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to integer using the to_integer function. Check the parameterised MUX:

```
architecture RTL of MUX is
begin
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- MUX_RTL
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Implements a multiplexer
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  MUX_RTL: process(DATA_IN, ADDR_IN)
    variable ADDR_IN_INT : integer range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH-1; -- holds the integer value of the address
  begin
    ADDR_IN_INT := to_integer(unsigned(ADDR_IN));
    DATA_OUT <= DATA_IN(ADDR_IN_INT);
  end process MUX_RTL;
end architecture RTL;
```